# Where do those cloud data overlay images come from

Tags: weather, cloud-cover, radar

Certain time-based (rain) cloud data appears on different sites and apps. This gives the impression that the rain and cloud data is available (for free or licensable), and that multiple sites make use of the same data.

Where do sat24, meteox, meteoradar, buienradar, rainydays and the likes get their cloud data from?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for [earthscience.se]

Comment: Data sources should be cited by the apps